# What's the point of installing Alexa SDK module into local node environment?

Tags: node.js, npm, alexa-skills-kit

I'm very new to Node.js, so perhaps my confusion stems from there. But as far as I can see it, there is no reason to install Alexa Skills Kit SDK when there is no native way to debug/test run my codes without using the simulator online.

I was following the tutorial to make [Facts Skill](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-fact), and noticed that I'm writing all of my code into the developer portal. I found a couple `npm` modules that allow me to test my Alexa Skill locally, but I want to know if there is any native support within the SDK for IO of request/respond JSON.

I guess I'm really confused because, normally when you install a module you use it directly in your script (e.g. You install the http module so that you can make http requests inside your code), but since there is no way to test the Alexa Skill out of the online simulator (which already has a built-in support for the SDK), it seems rather pointless to install the SDK as a module in my local environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would install that module, and anything else that your skill implementation depends on, into your local environment because you can and should test from your local environment.

You might be able to get by without local testing for small skills, but before long you will need local testing IMO.

There are many different ways to enable local testing.  Initially I did it by capturing some events that Alexa sent to my live skill, and then manually feeding those to my local skill implementation.  How exactly you do this depends on how you've implemented.

But now I'm using BSTAlexa which is a local Alexa simulator - it generates the events for you - and is great for setting up automatated testing.  You can read about how to use [it here](http://docs.bespoken.tools/en/latest/tutorials/tutorial_bst_emulator_nodejs/).

Comment: I would also add that you can use our [bst proxy tool](https://bespoken.tools/blog/2016/08/24/introducing-bst-proxy-for-alexa-skill-development) to send the requests from Alexa directly to your laptop. So, using that you can test with a real Alexa device (such as the Echo) or the Service Simulator but still be developing/debugging on your laptop. [More info here](https://bespoken.tools/blog/2016/08/24/introducing-bst-proxy-for-alexa-skill-development). It works well in conjunction with our emulator that Tom mentions.